# Вот такая проблема slash_discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

`discord_slash` на скриншоте ниже помечены жёлтой волнистой линией, что делать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Жёлтой линией показывается предупреждение.
Что делать? Наводить курсор и смотреть что там за предупреждение